# Optimize mysql query that take long execution time about 4 minutes

Tags: java, mysql, database-performance

```
 select nl.ndc, formulary_status FROM bh.webdav_formulary_detail wfd 
 INNER JOIN bh.payer_map pm ON wfd.payer_map_id = pm.payer_map_id 
 INNER JOIN bh.ndc_lookup nl ON wfd.product_id = nl.uid 
 WHERE pm.payer_id ='P00000000001001' 
   and pm.formulary_id='01244' 
   and nl.ndc in ('16590061572' , '35356078830' , '35356078860' , '35356078890' , 
                  '49999085690' , '54868381500' , '54868381501' , '54868381503' , 
                  '54868381504' , '54868381505' , '59011044010' , '59011044020' , 
                  '63629377401' , '63629377402' , '63629377403');
```

The below mysql tables is myisam engine

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE webdav_formulary_detail;

CREATE TABLE webdav_formulary_detail (
  product_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  formulary_status char(2) NOT NULL,
  file_iid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  payer_map_id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY payer_map_id (payer_map_id),
  KEY product_id (product_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE ndc_lookup (
  uid mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ndc char(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (uid),
  KEY uid (uid),
  KEY ndc (ndc)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE payer_map (
  payer_map_id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  payer_id varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  formulary_id varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  alternate_id varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (payer_map_id),
  KEY payer_map_id (payer_map_id),
  KEY payer_id (payer_id),
  KEY formulary_id (formulary_id),
  KEY alternate_id (alternate_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How i can optimize the above mysql query to improve its execution time to less than half minute ?

Comment: You should probably add some indices. Which ones? Check out the profiler: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Comment: Indeed, the first step certainly is to take a closer look at the indices. You can also "examine" your query to get insight. Simply prepend the word "examine" to your select query and analyze the result. Or even better: post the result here.

Comment: @zmbq - How would the profiler help in deciding what new index to add?

Comment: You can see which tables are scanned. Although `EXPLAIN SELECT` sounds like a good idea, too (I don't have any MySQL experience)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE pm.payer_id ='P00000000001001' 
  and pm.formulary_id='01244'
```

begs for a composite index on `payer_map`:  `INDEX(payer_id, formulary_id)` (or the opposite order).  Slightly better would be to switch to InnoDB or to create a 'covering' index: `INDEX(payer_id, formulary_id, payer_map_id)`.

1. The optimizer is likely to start with the table with the best filtering possibilities -- pm.  The `INDEX` I gave you will make that efficient.
2. The next table must be `wfd`, using `payer_map_id`.  `wfd` has a good index for that.
3. Finally `nl` will come in using `uid`.  Again there is a pretty good index.  Actually, `INDEX(uid, ndc)` would be slightly better because of being a "covering" index.  Or switching to InnoDB would be good because of the 'clustering' of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Always provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...;` to see what the optimizer is doing.

Unrelated to optimization:

```
PRIMARY KEY      (payer_map_id),
KEY payer_map_id (payer_map_id),
```

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY` is a `KEY`, hence the latter is totally redundant; `DROP` it.  Ditto for `uid`.

[My cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) has more on how to create indexes from a `SELECT`.